# Buildroot virtual package (openssl)

Tags: buildroot

Buildroot (https://buildroot.org) uses a virtual package to build the openssl library.

I can't find a hint neither in the corresponding package directory nor in the corresponding build directory which version of the openssl library is used.

I would like to define a openssl version myself. Where and how is the openssl version defined in the buildroot environment?

Answer (score 0):

A virtual package is used in Buildroot whenever several implementations of the same interface are available.

In case of openssl, there are two implementations: OpenSSL itself (in `package/libopenssl`) and LibreSSL (in `package/libressl`). You probably want to look at `package/libopenssl`.